# How to convert all _id fields in a mongodb collection to ObjectId type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have imported documents into a collection from a JSON file. I created the _id field using the node.js ObjectId function like so:

```
_id: ObjectId()
```

This creates the _id value which looks like this in the JSON document:

[image]

Once this is saved as JSON and loaded into mongodb, it is 'stringified' and is no longer an ObjectId type:

[image]

I now want to convert all _id properties in my mongoDb collection to ObjectId type.

I know that if I did not specify an _id, that mongo would have created one for me in the desired ObjectId type but this does not work for me as other collections that I have created already use this _id value that I have created.

Any idea how to convert all the documents _id to ObjectId type? What would the specific code be to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import Mongodb ObjectId from CSV file using mongoimport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329309/how-to-import-mongodb-objectid-from-csv-file-using-mongoimport)

Comment: I think the MongoDB driver understands that _id which is unique for a document is an ObjectId type but I'm not sure about that fact though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could follow the idea here. [change MongoDB id from string to objectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291819/change-mongodb-id-from-string-to-objectid)

Alternatively, since you seem to have access to the data, before importing into MongoDB, when generating your json, store the '_id' field in this format before importing.

```js
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "621cfa31f0fc870004a35a8c"
  }
```

The 'oid' tells MongoDB that the type is an object id.

Comment: Your post does not answer **How to convert all _id fields in a mingodb collection**.

Comment: The answer definitely not answer the question.
What to do if collection already owns more than 1k rows?

Answer (score 0):

In other to resolve this seamlessly, it is best you structure and define your schema such that the `_id` type is in sync with your mongoDB `_id`.
If your mongoDB `_id` type is a string.

```js
const mongoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,

  _id: String, //defining id to string type
  author: String,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number,

  tags: [String],
  date: Date,
})
```

If your MongoDB `_id` is an `ObjectId`, use this pattern and
MongoDB will create and match the `_id` to the `ObjectId` type seamlessly.

```js
const mongoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  author: String,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number,

  tags: [String],
  date: Date,
})
```